# Most Efficent way to Trasverse

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

Please see the edit at the bottom:

I'm using XPath to scrape some data from a site.  Im wondering if I'm perhaps using too many `foreach() loops`, and could traverse through the hierarchy in a simpler way. I feel I may be using too many queries, and that there may be a better way just using one

The hierarchy looks something like this.

```
<ul class='item-list'>
    <li class='item' id='12345'>
        <div class='this-section'>
            <a href='http://www.thissite.com'>
                <img src='http://www.thisimage.com/image.png' attribute_one='4567' attribute-two='some-words' />

        </div>
        <small class='sale-count'>Some Number</small>
    </li>
    <li class='item' id='34567'>
    <li class='item' id='48359'>
    <li class='item' id='43289'>
</ul>
```

So I did the following:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($file);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$list = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='item-list']/li");

foreach($list as $list_item)
{
$item['item_id'][] = $list_item->getAttribute('id');

$links = $xpath->query("div[@class='this-section']//a[contains(@href, 'item')]", $list_item);

foreach($links as $address)
{
    $href = $address->getAttribute('href');
    $item['link'][] = substr($href, 0, strpos($href, '?'));
}

$other_data = $xpath->query("div[@class='this-section']//*[@attribute-one]", $list_item);

foreach($other_data as $element)
{
    $item['cost'][] = $element->getAttribute('atribute-one');
    $item['category'][] = $element->getAttribute('attribute-two');
    $item['name'][] = $element->getAttribute('attribute-three');        

}

$sales = $xpath->query(".//small[@class='sale-count']", $list_item);

foreach($sales as $sale)
    $item['sale'][] = substr($sale->textContent, 0, strpos($sale->textContent, ' '));
 }
```

Do I need to constantly re-query to work my down the hierarchy, or is there a simpler way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**
So it seems I am indeed using too many foreach loops.  For every one I take out, I am save a ton of memory.  So my question becomes.

One I have parent element (in this case the `<li>`), is there not a way to pick elements and attributes out without re-querying and looping through the results?  I need to eliminate as many of these xpath subqueries, and foreach loops as I can.

Comment: looks rather neat to me.. :)

Comment: Though you could maybe loop through `$image->attributes` if you want *all* the attributes..

Comment: Ah alright good point, Ill try that!

Comment: @dtj - Your edited question is beyond the scope of your original question. I would revert the question back to its original state, then open a new question for your new problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you could use [`DOMElement::getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php) instead:

```
$images = $list_item->getElementsByTagName( 'img');
```

As for which is more efficient, you'd have to benchmark it. You have the speed comparison between a relative XPath query, or a preorder traversal of the `<li>`'s node tree.

Comment: Alright, thats true.  I'll keep that in my back pocket when Im doing performance tests!